How to get idToken from Facebook OAuth?
There is no API reference for swift in Supabase for sign in a user through facebook.
is there any other method for swift which i can use for facebook auth?
I have used
this snippet to use google provider to authorize user in supabase...
client.auth.signInWithIdToken(credentials: OpenIDConnectCredentials(
                    provider: provider,
                    idToken: idToken,
                    accessToken: accessToken
                ))


Have you checked the documentation for Facebook auth in supabase? https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/social-login/auth-facebook

they haven't provided api doc for swift.

if you follow the guide, you need to setup a facebook app for it to login to, then it shows you in other languages what steps you need to take, so you can use the same steps in swift. but at least that document explains the requirements and steps
